# Copy row and paste into multiple rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code, that will copy a row and paste it into multiple rows.

```
For i = 2 To 100
    Rows(101).Copy Rows(i)
Next i
```

This does work, but it takes a lot of resources, because of the copying is made 100 times.

Is there a way to optimize this code, so that the copying can be made once in advanced, instead of 100-times inside the For-loop ?

Have tried this, but this does throw an error. *"Object doesn't support this property or method"*

```
Rows(101).Copy

For i = 2 To 100
     Rows(i)
Next i
```

Comment: You probably need to tell VBA what to do with `Rows(i)` eg paste, otherwise VBA doesn't know what to do there. `Rows(i)` alone is just a reference to a row, no action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy it in just one line to all rows:

```
Rows(101).Copy Rows("2:100")
```

Comment: Perfect, did not know you could set a range in Rows!

Comment: @Fjott doesn't matter you can use `Range` too: `Rows(101).Copy Range("2:100")`